# Ordinal numbers in chapter number

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I'm working on a daily journal and I want every \chapter number to contain an ordinal indicator (st, nd, rd etc.). See attached picture as an example (I marked in red what I'm looking for). Is there a way for this to work in LaTeX? So for every chapter, LaTeX should output the ordinal indicator based on the number. So for chapter "2" it will be "2nd" and for "330" it will be "330th".

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=8.5in,paperwidth=5.5in]{geometry}
\geometry{showframe=false}
\geometry{margin=0.5in,bottom=0.70in, top=0.50in, bindingoffset=0.2in}
\usepackage[super,comma]{natbib}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.15} 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts}
\usepackage{blindtext} % tor the example text
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\rhd$}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[tableposition=above]{caption}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{tex4ebook}

%%% Chapter Heading %%%
\makeatletter
\def\thickhrule{\leavevmode \leaders \hrule height 0.5ex \hfill \kern \z@}
\def\position{\centering}
%% Note the difference between the commands the one is 
%% make and the other one is makes
\renewcommand{\@makechapterhead}[1]{%
  \vspace*{0.5\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \position \reset@font
        {\huge \scshape \thechapter}
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{5\p@}%
        \interlinepenalty\@M
        \thickhrule
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
        {\large \bfseries #1\par\nobreak}
        \par\nobreak
        \vspace*{2\p@}%
        \thickhrule
        \vskip 10\p@
  }}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title name}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12):

I suggest you employ the machinery of the [fmtcount](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fmtcount) package to achieve your formatting goal for chapter numbers.

[image]

How to "decorate" the chapter header further is a topic best left to another package, such as the [titlesec](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec) package.

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=8.5in,paperwidth=5.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{fmtcount}             % for "\ordinal" macro
\fmtcountsetoptions{fmtord=level} % don't raise the ordinal indicator

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\thechapter}{\ordinal{chapter}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Title name}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: The `fmtcount` package can provide ordinal numbers not just for English-language documents, but for quite a few other languages as well, and even for dialect forms within a given language. If you don't need this sophistication, you could load the [engord](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/engord) package (presumably with the option `normal`) instead and replace `\ordinal{chapter}` with `\engord{chapter}` in the third argument of `\patchcmd`.

Comment: Good to know! +1

Answer (score 2):

The `memoir` class (a superset of the `book` class) provides for both ordinal and cardinal numbers. Read the documentation, section 18.14 Number Formatting.